# How to change order of input fields that Grails generates

Tags: grails, netbeans, groovy

When Grails generates a view (like `create.gsp`) it puts all the attributes of a class in alphabetical order.  I would prefer the class attributes be listed in the order that I have them arranged in the class file.  I can move them around manually, but I was wondering, is there was a way to make Grails arrange it the way I want automatically?  I am using NetBeans if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever order they appear in the constraints block is how they will be generated.  So with the least amount of config you might have

```
static constraints = {
  username()
  firstName()
  lastName()
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I have the latest version of grails 2.3.3. Any idea?

Comment: Ignore the above comment. The ordering works as you mention. I had to redeploy the application to see the changes.